Performance Issues in Azure App Service with Container in .NET 8 app
I'm experiencing a performance issue in my .NET 8 application hosted on Azure App Service with a Docker Container. When I use Azure App Service only (without the container) with Azure SQL, the API requests are fast (2-3 seconds). However, when using Azure App Service with a Docker Container and Azure SQL, the same requests take around 5-20 seconds (varies in this range).
More information:

The API request in question is a simple GET request that executes a single query on Azure SQL.
I suspect that there might be connection issues leading to retries, but I'm not sure how to confirm this.
I believe this might be related to a network configuration issue in the Docker container, a missing configuration, or possibly something on the Azure SQL side, but I’m still not sure.
I see multiple SQL dependency events in Application Insights with similar timestamps, which might indicate a retry pattern, but I’m not experienced in reading end-to-end transaction details.

Questions:

How can I determine if these multiple SQL events are due to connection retries?
What might be causing the performance degradation in the containerized environment - compared to the standard Azure App Service setup?
What steps can I take to troubleshoot and resolve these potential connection issues?

What I've tried so far:

I've checked Application Insights for any error messages or failed dependency calls, but I’m not entirely sure what to look for.
I’ve reviewed the SQL query execution time, and it seems normal, but the repeated SQL events are concerning.
The container has sufficient resources allocated, and the network setup should be standard.

I have been dealing with this for weeks now. Any guidance or insights on how to resolve this performance issue would be greatly appreciated.

I'm also experiencing the same performance problem, not sure if it has something to do with DNS resolution or something.

how do you connect to Azure Sql? Is it through public internet?

@Artem Yes, that is correct.

You could try to ping the sql server from the docker container to see the connection and also try same from outside of the docker container. Have you got Chace to check the sql server logs? Try to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/transaction-search-and-diagnostics?tabs=transaction-search end-to-end transaction tracing feature in Application Insights. This can help you see the full timeline of an API request, from the incoming request to the SQL query execution, and identify where the delay occurs. IS it possible for you to set the database and web app in same region?
To confirm if the issue is related to the retries you could  app insight logs, look at the dependencyDuration, success, and resultCode fields of the SQL dependencies. If you see a pattern where the first attempt has a long duration or fails resultCode indicating a timeout or a connection issue, followed by successful attempts with shorter durations, this could indicate a retry. you could also check his post for more troubleshooting help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44957720/11147346
